Adding AuthCredential to Firebase user on the server
On the client, I can do something like this to update a Firebase user's phone number:
const confirmation = await app.auth().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
// ...
const credential = auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(confirmation.verificationId, verificationCode);
await user.updatePhoneNumber(credential);

However, I'd like to do certain database operations when a user changes their phone number, so it would be better to do update the phone number or the server and run the database updates in the same endpoint.
I can do auth.updateUser(uid, { phoneNumber }) on the server, but then the phone number is not verified.
Is it possible to check that a phone number was verified on the server or is there some other clean workaround?
Edit: Ideally, I could do this on the server side:
const credential = req.body.credential;
auth.updateUser(uid: { phoneNumber: credential });

which would fail if the credential is bad.

Firebase Authentication only provides a way to send SMS messages from its client-side SDKs. There's no way to trigger these from the server-side SDKs (as that'd open up a major abuse vector). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68508074/firebase-admin-user-authentication-not-sending-sms-only-creates-users-directly

I don't think there would be need to trigger SMS from the server side. All I would need is an endpoint in admin-sdk that does not take the new phone number as a plaintext parameter but the credentials instead. Am I missing something?

The functionality that you want just doesn't exist in Firebase Authentication.
